# Simple and quick oozie installation steps on unix

Tags: installation, oozie, distro

I am trying to install ozzie on my Unix machine, however i am getting error while executing the distro file.

I have tried making changes into pom.xml of oozie, but that also did not worked.
I hvae followed below links :

https://gauravkohli.com/2014/08/26/apache-oozie-installation-on-hadoop-2-4-1/
https://milindjagre.wordpress.com/2016/01/05/oozie-4-1-0-installation-on-hadoop-2-6-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Any help or installation guide will be great help.

Comment: did you find an easy way to install Oozie? I'm on Mac OS High Sierra and I don't know which files to keep on my local and which to move to my remote server.